# How to make the new cassandra cluster balanced after adding one or more nodes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

For testing here and describing the question simple, I used two nodes to build a `cassandra(2.1.11)` cluster (`192.168.56.110` and `192.168.56.111`), Now I added one additional node(`192.168.56.112`) to this cluster, and I hope my new ring balanced through using `nodetool move` command, but when I using the following steps:

1. Getting the `192.168.56.110`'s all token range, such as `981588427421702712 -- 1007755089748978774`
2. Getting the new node's all token range, such as `5458173168911717635 -- 5458821955945522089`
3. I executed the command:

   ```
    [root@test-1 pengcz]# ../cassandra-2.1.11/bin/nodetool  -h 192.168.56.110 -u admin -pw   admin4587 move 5458173168911717635
    error: target token 5458173168911717635 is already owned by another node.
    -- StackTrace --
    java.io.IOException: target token 5458173168911717635 is already owned by another node.
   ```

   According to the article [Load balancing](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations) said: `If you add nodes to your cluster your ring will be unbalanced and only way to get perfect balance is to compute new tokens for every node and assign them to each node manually by using nodetool move command.`,  I think I seemly understood `nodetool move` command wrong, But I don't know how to understand it and balance the new cluster? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using virtual nodes ? (**num_tokens** value set in **cassandra.yaml**). If yes, you don't need to use _nodetool move_ at all

Comment: @doanduyhai, Thank you! Yes, I set `num_tokens: 512`, so

Comment: @doanduyhai, Thank you! Your answer make me sure that I do not need to rebalance my cluster manually because I set `num_tokens: 512` in `cassandra.yaml`. After I set the configs and start new nodes' cassandra, the balance will go automatically? The only question is that the balance will take long time

Answer (score 0):

So, you changed settings num_tokens to 512. After starting new nodes you should remember that seed nodes doesn't bootstrap automatically, but other ones balanced data after start. To balance seed node you should run nodetool repair for you node. Time depends on data size.